# Inserting one row in a table with ODBC and C++

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

I would like to insert only one row in a Table, which is in MS SQL Server. I am using C++ and I want to do this job with ODBC. I have written a very basic example:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sql.h> 
#include <sqlext.h> 

int main()
{
 SQLHANDLE henv; 
 SQLHANDLE hdbc; 
 SQLHANDLE hstmt; 
 RETCODE rc;

char Statement[80] = "INSERT INTO TK.dbo.Infos( Firstname,Lastname) VALUES ('Max','Musterman')";

char dsn[10] = {"TK"}; //Name of Database in MSSQL Server
char user[5] = {""}; //I have windows Authentication, not user name and password for loggin to DB
char pass[5] = {""};

rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv);    
rc = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER) SQL_OV_ODBC3, SQL_IS_UINTEGER); 
rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc);  
rc = SQLConnect(hdbc, (SQLCHAR *)dsn, SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR *) user, SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR *) pass, SQL_NTS); 
rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT,hdbc,&hstmt); 
rc=SQLExecDirect(hstmt,(SQLCHAR *)Statement,SQL_NTS);

return 0;
}
```

If I am running this code, I get no errors or bugs, but it doesn't work properly. If I run the code step by step, at the first `rc=0` and in the last two lines `rc=-1`
Could you please help me to correct my code?

thnaks

Comment: You should check rc after each call.
You should chec Documentation of SQLExecDirect for example which return value is good. (MSDN)

if you get an error , you should try to get ODBC Error codes to get more information( see SQLGetDiagRec  ). 

See ODBC Documentation for complete examples.

For example: 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ODBC-sample-191624ae

Comment: I get no errors, nothing

Comment: SQLAllocHandle should return SQL_SUCCESS, which is defined as 0, not -1.
You said, last two lines returns -1
you should abort after each ODBC call, if rc is not SQL_SUCCESS.
Always look for the first error. ;)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Hope this helps, or I don't understand the question/problem. ;)

Comment: Sorry, I am really new in C++ and OBDC. How can I extract the error?

Comment: Please try to look in documentation of SQLGetDiagRec , or google, there are many examples.
Call SQLGetDiagRec until you get NO_DATA ... there can be multiple messages after each call.
in the simple form, output it only.

complete samples is little bit to long here.

Comment: @Kaja  dsn is not supposed to be the name of the database. It's the name of the data source. I'm not sure if it default to a dsn in windows. take a look at the last example in this link for simple handling of errors http://k3ut0i.github.io/linux/2015/08/09/odbc-setup-linux.html

Comment: @keutoi thank you for your hint. I have found my DNS name, but it doesn't work with the correct DNS name either.

Comment: @Kaja Do some error handling and see which statement fails exactly. look at the example in link i've provided above.